# "Describe something as" or "Describe something by"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Which one is correct?

> She describes these classes **as** trivial

Or

> She describes these classes **by** trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you describe something **as** X, you are saying that it *is* X. So you can describe something as trivial, or describe someone as tall, or describe a landscape as barren.

If you describe something **by** X, then X is a *category* of characteristic that you might describe it *as*. So you can describe something *by appearance*, or *by size*.

Thus, in your example, you want to use ***as***.